# Is there a way to use LINQ to select a range of items based on an enclosing condition (i.e. not a simple WHERE clause)?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Consider you have a `List<Foo>` of objects and `Foo` has an `IsSelected` property like so...

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected{ get; set; }
}

List<Foo> sourceItems = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo(){ Name="First",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Second",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Third",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Fourth",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Fifth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Sixth",   IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Seventh", IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Eighth",  IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Ninth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Tenth",   IsSelected=false}
};
```

Using a Where clause, I can of course get just the items that are selected, like so...

```
var results = sourceItems.Where(item => item.IsSelected);
```

...but what if I want all items between the first and last items where IsSelected is true?  (i.e. Second through Seventh)

I know I can use SkipWhile since it skips until the first true statement, then returns everything after...

```
// Returns from Second on
var results = sourceItems.SkipWhile(item => !item.IsSelected);
```

...and I know I can reverse and do the same again, but then I'd have to re-reverse at the end and double-reversing just feels like it would be unnecessarily expensive.

My other thought is to use the Select with index and store the last index where IsSelected is true, then use a Where clause at the end, checking if the index is below the last selected one, but that just seems expensive and cludgy.

```
int lastSelectedIndex = -1;
var results = sourceItems
    .SkipWhile(item => !item.IsSelected)
    .Select( (item, itemIndex) => 
    {
        if(item.IsSelected)
            lastSelectedIndex = index;

        return new {item, index};
    })
    .Where(anonObj => anonObj.index <= lastSelectedIndex)
    .Select(anonObj => anonObj.Item);
```

Alternately I think I can replace that last `Where` with a `Take` clause and just take the correct number of items so I wouldn't have to iterate the entire list, but I'm not sure lastSelectedIndex will have the correct value as I don't think Select returns the entire list, only the next enumeration, but I could be wrong.

```
.Take(lastSelectedIndex + 1);
```

So is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let me approach this differently by using indices and adding up the items to a new collection.

```
List<Foo> sourceItems = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo(){ Name="First",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Second",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Third",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Fourth",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Fifth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Sixth",   IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Seventh", IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Eighth",  IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Ninth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Tenth",   IsSelected=false}
};

int startIndex = sourceItems.FindIndex(x => x.IsSelected);
int endIndex   = sourceItems.FindLastIndex(x => x.IsSelected);

var items = new List<Foo>();

for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
    items.Add(sourceItems[i]);
```

With 1 000 000 entries it only took 13 Milliseconds to get the result out.

Comment: Couldn't you just have used a where clause there instead of creating a new collection? (i.e. sourceItems.Where( (item, itemIndex) => itemIndex >= startIndex && itemIndex <= endIndex) ) rather than creating a new collection?  Also, while I know of this solution, I didn't know if there was such a thing already in LINQ. (Also, I cleaned up your code.)

Comment: Unfortunately where condition does not help here - how do you want to detect the current index where you are? By using FindIndex / FindLastIndex  I just follow what you asked for :)

Comment: @MarqueIV you could try [GetRange(index, count)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) instead of his for-loop

Comment: @WiiMaxx Yep, totally forgot about this one :)

Comment: @Dimi, how does the Where condition not help?  I just gave you the exact syntax that does it using the overload that gives you the index: (i.e. Where((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex >= startIndex && itemIndex <= endIndex).

Comment: BTW, in testing, I just confirmed that GetRange was the fastest.  Actually, getting the two indexes first, then using GetRange was the fastest of all the ones I've tested.  However, since it requires two additional iterations of the source rather than doing it all in one linq statement like I'm seeing elsewhere, I'm torn if this, or that one should be the answer.  Let me see how others vote on it first.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `.Aggregte` and only iterate once but it is a bit messy:

```
var lists = sourceItems.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new List<Foo>(), new List<Foo>()), (acc, foo) =>
{
    if (foo.IsSelected)
    {
        acc.Item1.AddRange(acc.Item2);
        acc.Item2.Clear();
        acc.Item2.Add(foo);
    }
    else if (acc.Item2.Any())
    {
        acc.Item2.Add(foo);
    }
    return acc;
});

if (lists.Item2.Any()) lists.Item1.Add(lists.Item2.First());
```

As you can see this solution is not very *pure* but you can always copy around lists inside (C#s syntax is just not very good for this kind of things so I did stick with old-school imperative programming here)

The idea is simple: you have two lists - the first will be the result and in the second you accumulate all objects till you hit another `selected` - if you do you append the accumulator to the first list and start with a new accumulator.

The last line is there because the algorithm missed the last `selected`.

### If performance is involved

**go all the way**

```
static IEnumerable<Foo> BetweenSelected(List<Foo> foos)
{
    var lastSelected = foos.Count;

    for (var i = 0; i < foos.Count; i++)
    {
        var foo = foos[i];
        if (foo.IsSelected)
        {
            for (var j = lastSelected; j < i; j++)
                yield return foos[j];
            lastSelected = i+1;
            yield return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

You can even change it to return another List and replace the `yield`s by `List.Add` if you want.

Comment: This is a good example of chasing performance doesn't always work. This solution produces the correct result but it is slower than the "double-reverse" approach. This took me 2.267 seconds to process a list of 10,000,000 items compared to 1.949 seconds using the double-reverse approach.

Comment: @Enigmativity if you want performance then LINQ is not the best way - just use imperative all the way (see my edit)

Comment: Oh yes, I couldn't agree with you more. My point was that performance only becomes an issue if you have millions of objects in the list. So going with the simplest LINQ is usually the way to go. Imperative is almost always faster but harder to maintain. You could always go to the extreme and write the code in assembler - that's the fastest - but it's not maintainable. Go with simple LINQ 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @Carsten, your edit looks interesting, but I'm having a little difficulty following the double yield return, especially since on initial glance, it appears to return these in reverse order. You also have J < I but that too is throwing me.  Can you add comments explaining what's going on there?  It would also help others visiting the page.  Thanks!

Comment: the last `yield` will return the ones with the `IsSelected` flag - the loop before will yield all the elements from just after the last `IsSelected`-element (`lastSelected = i+1`) to just before the current (`j < i`) - if you would try to do it like `j <= i` (removing the last yield) you would miss the very first one, till this case is special (none seen before)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass index in Where and use that in condition.

```
var result = sourceItems.Where((ele, index) => 
             index > 0 && index < 7 && ele.IsSelected);
```

**Edit** based on comments, you can get the indexes with `IsSelected` set to true and use `Min` and `Max` to get the start and end index that could be use in `Where` condition to get the records in that range.

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, sourceItems.Count)
                        .Where(i => sourceItems[i].IsSelected);
var result1 = sourceItems.Where((el, idx)=>idx >= indexes.Min() &&  idx <= indexes.Max());
```

Comment: Dude... thanks, but that's kind of off-topic.  This is pseudo-code I typed from my head to show the issue we have, not actual code.  Still, I made the changes.  Also, your answer doesn't appear to address what I'm after here since I'm not sure where you got 0 and 7 from.

Comment: I got 0 and 7 from OP (i.e. Second through Seventh), What elements you want ? do you want to exclude first and last and then check what objects have IsSelected = true, or first you want to filter all objects with IsSelected = true and then exclude first and last?

Comment: No, the range is based on the first and last item with IsSelected being set to true.  As called out in my question's details, I am looking for the range of items between the first and last selected items regardless of whether or not the items in between are also selected or not.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Check my update, I think this will give you the output you want but I am not sure how efficient it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial instinct was right. Go with this:

```
var results =
    sourceItems
        .SkipWhile(x => x.IsSelected == false)
        .Reverse()
        .SkipWhile(x => x.IsSelected == false)
        .Reverse();
```

An unless your list contains millions of items then it isn't going to much of a performance issue.

I just tried this code with 1,000,000 elements in the list and it completed in 163 milliseconds on my three year old laptop. 10,000,000 only took 1.949 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it would be this.  It's the easiest to code and maintain and is clear to other people editing the code too, which can't be understated.  We're only talking a few thousand objects, but there's actually a lot more to the LINQ statement than just this part so it's still pretty slow.  But you showed the slowdown isn't in this portion of the query so I think this is what we'll go with.  Lemme give it a little more time to hear about other answers as well as the explanation of @Carsten's edit.  If nothing more interesting comes up, you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dimi Toulakis [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604044/1993545)

if someone need this often in his code here is an extension

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static List<T> FindGroup<T>(this List<T> mylist, Predicate<T> pred)
    {
        var first = mylist.FindIndex(pred);
        var last = mylist.FindLastIndex(pred);
        last += 1; // to get the Last Element

        return mylist.GetRange(first, last - first);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining [Dimi Toulakis's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24604044/2300466) and [Adil's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603079/2300466) :

```
List<Foo> sourceItems = new List<Foo>{
    new Foo(){ Name="First",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Second",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Third",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Fourth",  IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Fifth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Sixth",   IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Seventh", IsSelected=true },
    new Foo(){ Name="Eighth",  IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Ninth",   IsSelected=false},
    new Foo(){ Name="Tenth",   IsSelected=false}
};

int startIndex = sourceItems.FindIndex(item => item.IsSelected);
int endIndex   = sourceItems.FindLastIndex(item => item.IsSelected);

var result = sourceItems.Where((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex >= startIndex && itemIndex <= endIndex);
```

We can also use **GetRange()** but it isn't LINQ.

**Update**

Another way that seems to be more efficient is using **TakeWhile()** together with **SkipWhile()**:

```
int endIndex = sourceItems.FindLastIndex(item => item.IsSelected);

var result = sourceItems
    .TakeWhile((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex <= endIndex) // Take all before (and including) index of last match (must be before SkipWhile as that would change the index)
    .SkipWhile(item => !item.IsSelected); // Skip up until the first item where IsSelected is true
```

That also saves us the step of having to find the startIndex.

Comment: Actually, the logic in your 'Update' is flawed as the index in the TakeWhile clause is the index calculated *after* the skips, so that index is off by the number of items you've skipped, meaning it returns **count-of-skipped-items** more than its supposed to.

Comment: @MarqueIV calling `TakeWhile` before `SkipWhile` solves the problem. thanks for your comment. answer updated

Comment: Also, I just re-ran your examples and the fastest *does* use the GetRange call so I'm not sure why you claim Where is faster than GetRange. GetRange beat both the Where (which was the slowest) and the TakeWhile/SkipWhile (which was the middle) options.  You can test this by using the Stopwatch object in code.

Comment: the results I see there also show GetRange being the fastest.  Here they are...  
00:00:00.0006275 (GetRange)  
00:00:00.0031368 (Where)  
00:00:00.0062290 (TakeWhile/SkipWhile)

Comment: @MarqueIV sometimes the first execution gives different results, but generally my results are around this >> 00:00:00.0005427 (GetRange) 00:00:00.0005281 (Where) 00:00:00.0003741 (TakeWhile/SkipWhile).. Anyway, GetRange isn't LINQ